# creating typerscript classes in separate files and using them in angular2 components

Tags: typescript, angular

We are developing a new App in Angular2 with typescript. Is there any cleaner way to declare all the classes and interfaces in separate files and referencing them in angular2 components .

```
import {Component, OnInit, Pipe} from 'node_modules/angular2/core';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http, Response, Headers } from 'node_modules/angular2/http';
import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, Router } from 'node_modules/angular2/router';
import { Observable } from 'node_modules/rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-App',
  templateUrl: '/app/Index.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, NewEvent]   })
//instead of writing class here , is there any way to declare this class in a
//separate file and injecting it here. 
export class Events    {    }
```

Comment: All your imports at the top of the line import classes from other files. You can do the same. See also http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the class of components within the same module than decorators applied on them.

```
@Component({ // Applied decorator
  (...)
})
export class Events { // Component class
}
```

Decorators and classes can be imported from other modules:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'; // decorator from Angular2

import {SomeOtherClass} from './some-module'; // custom class
```